# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.fetchResults is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello i begin in react redux i try to play with an api my problem is at begining in my idea i hope make a select and in the select all the results for a day:

My Component ResultListItems:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchResults } from "../actions/index";



class ResultListItems extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
      this.props.fetchResults();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Coucou la liste resultats</h2>
        <select></select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    results: state.resultsReducer.results
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ResultListItems)
```

My Action in index.js in folder actionsat this moment i have a date in url

```
import axios from "axios";

export const GET_RESULTS = "GET_RESULTS";

const END_POINT = "http://data.nba.net/10s/20200203";

export function fetchResults() {
  return function(dispatch) {
      axios.get(`${END_POINT}`)
            .then(axiosResponse => {
        dispatch({ type: GET_RESULTS, payload: axiosResponse.data});
      });
  }
}
```

My reducer => reducer_results :

```
const initialResults ={
  results: []
}

export default function (state = initialResults, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_RESULTS:
      return {
        results: action.payload
      };
  }
  return state
}
```

I import in index.js in reducer Folder:

```
import ReducerResults from "../reducers/reducer_results";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  resultsReducer: ReducerResults
});

export default rootReducer;
```

And my container is results.js :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ResultListItems from '../components/results_list_item'

class Results extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App NBA</h1>
        <ResultListItems />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(Results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not mapping your api call of fetchResults to props.Try the following. After mapping state to props, map dispatch as well to props in component ResultListItems.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        fetchResults : () => dispatch(fetchResults()),
        dispatch
    }
 }
```

then coonect it like this.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ResultListItems)
```

Comment: Yes it works thank you i'm sorry i begin in react, redux in my head it was not necessary to dispatch to props because i don't modify the store but i have to push this point thx

Answer (score 0):

So, you haven't fetchResults in the list of props, this.props.fetchResults is undefined, because you haven't binded the action to the component's props. To deal with it you need to bind the actionCreator. Use a guide: https://blog.benestudio.co/5-ways-to-connect-redux-actions-3f56af4009c8

Or
just do like that:

`componentWillMount(){
  const {dispatch} = this.props;
  dispatch(fetchResults());
}`